# How do I move all files output from a command?

Tags: bash, command-line, scripting, command, move

I have this grep command to find files without the word Attachments in them.

```
grep -L -- Attachments *
```

I want to move all the files that are output from that command. How do I do that in bash? Do I use a pipe? Do I use a more wordy if/then statement in a full-on script?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you know that none if the file names contain new lines, tabs, spaces or glob combinations that may produce a match, this may be easier for a one off case:

```
mv $(grep -L Attachments *) dest_dir
```

Answer (score 36):

What you want to do is use a pipe and  `grep`s `-Z` option:

**Using GNU grep and mv**

```
grep -LZ -- Attachments * | xargs -0 mv -t target_directory
```

The `-Z` combined with `xargs -0` handles any filenames with special characters.

**Using BSD grep and mv** (like on MacOS X)

```
grep -L --null -- Attachments * |
while IFS= read -r -d "" file; do 
    mv "./$file" target_directory
done
```

On BSD, `grep -Z` means *decompress*, `grep --null` works on both BSD and GNU. BSD `mv` lacks option `-t`